# error from AsyncTask thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app in android which retrieve a picture from `http` page.I'm asking for this picture using an AsyncTask thread.

This is how I do it:

```
 mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for(int i=0;i<friends.size();i++)
                    {
           getUserPic(friends.get(i).getId());
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have an `ArrayList` called `friends` and for every item of the list I'm calling the method: `getUserPic()` which executes a `AyncTask` thread:

```
public void getUserPic(String userID){
        final String imageURL;
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
        task.execute(new String[] {imageURL});

    }
```

So everytime is called `getUserPic()` uses an AsyncTask thread to call for the `imageURL`.

The problem is that I get FC....here is how my logcat looks like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:380)
   at com.facebook.android.Example.getUserPic(Example.java:129)
   at com.facebook.android.Example$3.onClick(Example.java:114)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
   at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
```

Anyone, any SOLUTION to this?Thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void getUserPic(String userID){
        final String imageURL;
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
       new task().execute(new String[] {imageURL});

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using the same `task` object for each iteration of the loop (which is why the error says "the task is already running"). You can fix this by creating a new task object for each iteration, e.g.

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.execute(new String[] {imageURL});
```

However doing so might be quite wastfull if you end up starting a lot of tasks. So you may be better to have one task and give it a list of images to download. E.g.

```
ids = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<friends.size();i++)
{
    ids.add(friends.get(i).getId());
}
getUserPics(ids);
```

Then your `getUserPic` method would pass all the IDs on to a single task instance.

```
public void getUserPics(List<String> userIDs){
  final String imageURL;
  Bitmap bitmap=null;

  String[] imageURLs = new String[userIDs.legnth()];
  for(int i = 0; i < userIDs.length(); i++) {
     imageURLs[i] ="http://graph.facebook.com/"+userIDs[i]+"/picture?type=small";
  }

  task.execute(imageURLs);
}
```

Doing it this way, you'll probably want to use `publishProgress` on `AsyncTask` to update your UI with the images you've downloaded so far, rather than waiting until the end when you have them all.

Comment: this is a much better answer, you could always unselect the other answer and mark this one as the correct one :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this case the error is quite self descriptive. The task is in fact already running. Because you're running it in a loop, you need to initialize a new async task for each iteration and kick that one off.

Ahh, the joys of parallelized code :)

Comment: I know that...but I don't know how to fix it!!There is no sleep method for it.So I'm asking for a solution!!!